# Attribute data is not supported by the GeometryProvider in th Sharpmap

Tags: wpf, sharpmap, mapcontrol

Attribute data is not supported by the GeometryProvider.

SharpMap.UI ver 1.2.0.0

I want to make a click event on the image("maker"). so I used the following sample code URL.
https://xaml.dev/post/2006/05/18/Using-NetTopologySuite-in-SharpMap

but I face the exception.(SharpMap/Data/Providers/GeometryProvider.cs line 211)
What do I make a source code in function("OnExecuteIntersectionQuery", "ExecuteIntersectionQuery")?

[image]

[image]

```
  //Convert click-point in image coordinates to world coordinates
    Envelope ClickPnt = new Envelope(mapBox.Map.ImageToWorld(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataSet ds = new SharpMap.Data.FeatureDataSet();
    //Execute click-query on first layer in layers collection
    (mapBox.Map.Layers[1] as SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer).DataSource.ExecuteIntersectionQuery(ClickPnt, ds);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) //We have a result
    {
        //Add clicked features to a new selection layer
    }

public override void ExecuteIntersectionQuery(Envelope box, FeatureDataSet ds)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Attribute data is not supported by the GeometryProvider.");
}
```